# Fast with Literal but Slow with Variable

Tags: performance, oracle10g

I have a query that runs against a pretty large table. This query runs in a few seconds

```
SELECT *
    FROM KMDW.FT_DEPOSIT_TRANS a
   WHERE a.DEBIT_CREDIT_IND IN ('C', 'D')
     AND a.CLIENT_NO = '03263872'
     AND a.sym_run_date BETWEEN '01-jan-2022' AND '01-mar-2023'
     AND a.ACCT_NO = a.ACCT_NO;
```

Explain SQL

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Plan hash value: 3678647848                                                                                                |
                                                                                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    |
| Id  | Operation                          | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    |
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |                  |   193 | 52882 | 13021 (100)| 00:00:14 |       |       |    |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| FT_DEPOSIT_TRANS |   193 | 52882 | 13021 (100)| 00:00:14 | ROWID | ROWID |    |
|*  2 |   INDEX SKIP SCAN                  | DEP_TRN_INDX3    |    87 |       | 13012 (100)| 00:00:14 |       |       |    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    |
                                                                                                                           |
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                        |
---------------------------------------------------                                                                        |
                                                                                                                           |
   1 - filter("A"."DEBIT_CREDIT_IND"='C' OR "A"."DEBIT_CREDIT_IND"='D')                                                    |
   2 - access("A"."SYM_RUN_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2022-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND                            |
              "A"."CLIENT_NO"='03263872' AND "A"."SYM_RUN_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2023-03-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))|
       filter("A"."CLIENT_NO"='03263872' AND "A"."ACCT_NO" IS NOT NULL)                                                    |
```

However, if I query the view like this it takes 6 minutes.

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM KMDW.FT_DEPOSIT_TRANS a
   WHERE a.DEBIT_CREDIT_IND IN ('C', 'D')
     AND a.CLIENT_NO = nvl(:IP_CLIENT_NO, a.CLIENT_NO)
     AND a.sym_run_date BETWEEN :IP_FROM_DATE AND :IP_TO_DATE
     AND a.ACCT_NO = nvl(:IP_ACCT_NO, a.ACCT_NO);
```

Explain SQL

```
"PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT"
Plan hash value: 3191324441
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |                  |     1 |   274 |   384K (10)| 00:06:28 |       |       |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| FT_DEPOSIT_TRANS |     1 |   274 |   384K (10)| 00:06:28 | ROWID | ROWID |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | DEP_TRN_INDX9    |   176 |       |   384K (10)| 00:06:28 |       |       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
"   1 - filter(""A"".""CLIENT_NO""=NVL('03263872',""A"".""CLIENT_NO"") AND (""A"".""DEBIT_CREDIT_IND""='C' OR "
"              ""A"".""DEBIT_CREDIT_IND""='D'))"
"   2 - access(""A"".""SYM_RUN_DATE"">=TO_DATE(' 2022-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "
"              ""A"".""SYM_RUN_DATE""<=TO_DATE(' 2023-03-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))"
"       filter(""A"".""ACCT_NO""=NVL(NULL,""A"".""ACCT_NO""))"
```

If I use a literal the query runs in a few seconds but when I put the values in as variables (which I need to do) the query takes forever and presumably does a full table scan. I just want to know how I can fix it

Comment: "and presumably does a full table scan." You can look at the explain plan and see that it changes from an "index skip scan" to an "index range scan". It does not do a "full table scan".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AND a.ACCT_NO = a.ACCT_NO` in the first query is effectively the same as `AND a.ACCT_NO IS NOT NULL` (since `NULL` values are never equal to anything, even themselves).

In the second query, you use `NVL` rather than literals. You can rewrite the query so that it does not include functions:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   KMDW.FT_DEPOSIT_TRANS
WHERE  DEBIT_CREDIT_IND IN ('C', 'D')
AND    ( CLIENT_NO = :IP_CLIENT_NO OR :IP_CLIENT_NO IS NULL )
AND    sym_run_date BETWEEN :IP_FROM_DATE AND :IP_TO_DATE
AND    ( ACCT_NO = :IP_ACCT_NO OR :IP_ACCT_NO IS NULL);
```

If you need to also check that `CLIENT_NO` and `ACCT_NO` are non-`NULL` then:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   KMDW.FT_DEPOSIT_TRANS
WHERE  DEBIT_CREDIT_IND IN ('C', 'D')
AND    (  CLIENT_NO = :IP_CLIENT_NO
       OR ( :IP_CLIENT_NO IS NULL AND CLIENT_NO IS NOT NULL ) )
AND    sym_run_date BETWEEN :IP_FROM_DATE AND :IP_TO_DATE
AND    (  ACCT_NO = :IP_ACCT_NO
       OR ( :IP_ACCT_NO IS NULL AND ACCT_NO IS NOT NULL ) );
```

You can then compare the explain plans (we can't easily do that as we do not have your tables, indexes, data or statistics).

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell, but what seems to be *obviously* wrong is that you're comparing date to string; Oracle will try (and usually succeed) in implicit datatype conversion, but - you should take control over it.

Presuming `a.sym_run_date` column's datatype is `DATE`, this:

```
AND a.sym_run_date BETWEEN '01-jan-2022' AND '01-mar-2023'
```

should be rewritten to (using `DATE` literals)

```
AND a.sym_run_date BETWEEN DATE '2022-01-01' AND DATE '2023-03-01'
```

or (using `TO_DATE` function with appropriate format model)

```
AND a.sym_run_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.01.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
                       AND TO_DATE('01.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

---

Similarly, this:

```
AND a.sym_run_date BETWEEN :IP_FROM_DATE AND :IP_TO_DATE
```

should be e.g. (if you pass values like `'01-jan-2022'` to variable)

```
AND a.sym_run_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(:IP_FROM_DATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english')
                       AND TO_DATE(:IP_TO_DATE  , 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english')
```